# How can we get SBJSON connectionDidFinishLoading method inside array or Dictionary data in another class

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get one class array data in another class(i.e connectionDidFinishLoading array data i want to get in mainview class)

BackGroundClass.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "JSON.h"
@interface BackGroundClass : UIViewController<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
@end


BackGroundClass.m

@interface BackGroundClass ()
    {
        NSMutableData * webData;
        NSURLConnection * connection;
        NSMutableArray * array;
    }

    @end

        @implementation BackGroundClass

        - (void)viewDidLoad {

            array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            NSURL * url  = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising"];

            NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

            connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

            if(connection)
            {
                webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
            }
            [super viewDidLoad];
        }

        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
            [webData setLength:0];
        }

        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
            [webData appendData:data];
        }

        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
            NSLog(@"error is %@",[error localizedDescription]);
        }

       - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {


            NSString * allDataDictionbary = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSDictionary * responseString = [allDataDictionbary JSONValue];

            NSArray * allTweets = [responseString objectForKey:@"loans"];


            for (NSDictionary * obj in allTweets) {

                NSDictionary * act=[obj objectForKey:@"location"];
                NSDictionary * act1 = [ act objectForKey:@"geo"];
                NSString * level = [act1 objectForKey:@"pairs"];

                //NSDictionary * act = [obj objectForKey:@"description"];
                //NSArray * languages = [act objectForKey:@"languages"];
                //NSString * name = [[languages objectAtIndex:obj]objectForKey:@"name"];

               [array addObject:level];
            }

            NSLog(@"act array is %@",array);
        }

        - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
            [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        }
        @end


Now connectionDidFinishLoading methods inside  array data i want to get in mainView class how can i get please help me some one else
```

MainView.h

#import

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController

@end

MainView.m

## import "ViewController2.h"

```
    @interface ViewController2 ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController2

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

    }
    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Notification**

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to send notification from your connection class. And in the main view controller add a observer to the notification. There are two options to pass data via NSNotification userInfo dictionary & the object arg in the notification object.

http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/

**Delegation**

Create a delegate and assign the main VC as the delegate & call the delegate method with the data you get from the response

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm

Once you are familiar with the above concepts have a look at the following options

**Blocks**

http://www.appcoda.com/objective-c-blocks-tutorial/

**RAC Signals (Reactive cocoa)**

http://nshipster.com/reactivecocoa/

**Edit - Using Delegate**

***BackGroundClass.h***

```
@protocol MyConnectioDelegate <NSObject>
//using id type here, so NSArray or NSDictionary objects can be passed
-(void)didRecieveResponse:(id)aCollection;

@end
@interface BackGroundClass : UIViewController<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
@property(weak, nonatomic)id<MyConnectioDelegate>delegate;
@end
```

***BackGroundClass.m***

```
   - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
          ....
         //Once you get the collection.
          [_delegate didRecieveResponse:<theCollection>];
      }
```

***ViewController2.m***

```
@interface ViewController2 ()< MyConnectioDelegate >

    @end
    @implementation ViewController2

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
//Hope you already have the object of BackGroundClass created
_backgroundClassObject.delegate = self;


    }
    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    }

    -(void)didRecieveResponse:(id)aCollection{
//You have the collection sent from background class
}


@end
```

Comment: i am not understand what you people saying i think here better to use protocols please explain me used that protocols topic with example